# Bazel: set runtime environment variable and configuration file location for cc_binary/cc_test

Tags: c++, bazel

I am trying to use odbc++ in a C++ application on linux. The following build file is used to include the library as an external dependency

```
licenses(["notice"])
cc_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs=["lib/libodbc.so","lib64/libodbc++-mt.so"],
    hdrs=glob(["include/**/*.h","include/*.h"]),
    includes = ["include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    linkstatic = 1,
    data = [ "odbc.ini", "odbcinst.ini" ]
)
```

My bash profile has ODBCINI and OBCDINST set so running the binary directly from command line is fine. However, the environment variable ODBCINI and ODBCINST are not set when running bazel test.

Is there anyway to include the configuration files and set the run time environment variables to them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set environment variables for test execution in bazel with the `--test_env` flag. The documentation is [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html).

For example, `bazel build --test_env ODBCINI=foo //my:test`

Answer (score 0):

For `bazel test`

```
bazel test //:mytest --test_env=MYENV=myvalue
```

For `bazel run`

```
MYRUN=value bazel run //:myproject
```

For `bazel build`

```
bazel build //:myproject --action_env=MYENV=myvalue
```

Thanks to KevinSimper, reference https://www.kevinsimper.dk/posts/how-to-bazel-pass-environment-variables