# How to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH while using bazel? Or is there a way to avoid using LD_LIBRARY_PATH while using bazel?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ld, bazel

I want to import some .so files in my python code which is using bazel. For this i have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running the program other wise I am getting an error

ImportError: libsquishrunnerlib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But I want to do this using bazel or some otherway because I don't like the idea of setting the env variable on every machine  my program has to run

Comment: Would wrapping the `bazel` invocation in a `env` command be an option for you? e.g. `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path bazel run :main`. This way you won't need to set the variable globally for each machine.

Comment: You are calling squishrunner from Bazel, and want LD_LIBRARY_PATH be set for squishrunner in this case? Perhaps this has been addressed in [Bazel: set runtime environment variable and configuration file location for cc_binary/cc_test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944933/bazel-set-runtime-environment-variable-and-configuration-file-location-for-cc-b) already?